# How can I get the last completed service of each technician in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this relation

[image]

I am triyin to get the **last completed** (`Servicio.FechaTermino`) **service** (`Servicio`) **of each technician** (`Tecnico`).

With this query:

```
SELECT FechaTermino as FechaTermino, idTecnico, Latitud, Longitud, Nombre, Apellido, Flag, idServicio
FROM Servicio, Tecnico, Servicio_Tecnico
WHERE Servicio.idServicio = Servicio_Tecnico.Servicio_idServicio
AND Tecnico.idTecnico = Servicio_Tecnico.Tecnico_idTecnico
AND Completado = 1
```

I get this:

[image]

Watch the `idServico = 52`

When I use `Max` Function to try to get the last completed service of each technician,

```
SELECT Max(FechaTermino) as FechaTermino, idTecnico, Latitud, Longitud, Nombre, Apellido, Flag, idServicio
FROM Servicio, Tecnico, Servicio_Tecnico
WHERE Servicio.idServicio = Servicio_Tecnico.Servicio_idServicio
AND Tecnico.idTecnico = Servicio_Tecnico.Tecnico_idTecnico
AND Completado = 1
Group by idTecnico
```

this happen

[image]

the `idServicio=52` dissapear and it considering the `idServicio = 8` like the last completed service

How can I get the last completed service of each technician?

Comment: It looks like that fields Latitud, Longitud, IdSevicio keep changing always...

Comment: This is a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] question. Follow the tag for many answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT UNO.* FROM 
   (SELECT FechaTermino AS FechaTermino, idTecnico, Latitud, Longitud, Nombre, Apellido, Flag, idServicio
   FROM Servicio, Tecnico, Servicio_Tecnico
   WHERE Servicio.idServicio = Servicio_Tecnico.Servicio_idServicio
   AND Tecnico.idTecnico = Servicio_Tecnico.Tecnico_idTecnico
   AND Completado = 1) AS UNO

LEFT OUTER JOIN 

   (SELECT FechaTermino AS FechaTermino, idTecnico, Latitud, Longitud, Nombre, Apellido, Flag, idServicio
   FROM Servicio, Tecnico, Servicio_Tecnico
   WHERE Servicio.idServicio = Servicio_Tecnico.Servicio_idServicio
   AND Tecnico.idTecnico = Servicio_Tecnico.Tecnico_idTecnico
   AND Completado = 1) AS DOS

ON (UNO.idTecnico = DOS.idTecnico AND UNO.FechaTermino < DOS.FechaTermino)
WHERE DOS.idTecnico IS NULL;
```

Comment: Funcionó, gracias, muchas gracias.